# Tail Call Optimization for Quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm just getting into TCO and I understand the concept of how it reuses a single stack frame rather than creating a new one each time the method calls itself.  I intuitively want to compare this structure to a `while` loop as the loop will continually perform an operation on a set of variables until the condition isn't met.

However, given that TCO uses only one stack frame it seems like performing a sorting algorithm such as quicksort wouldn't be possible using TCO as a reference to the stack frames would be needed once the recursive method "unwinds" back up the call stack once the base case is reached.  Without a reference to the number of times the method was called, how does it know which subsequent operation to perform and how many times to perform it?

Given the method body for each call is the same I guess it could just keep a reference to the number of times the method has been called and then a pointer inside the method body of where to start execution but that's just a guess.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCO can be performed whenever a recursive call is in the final position.  Quicksort requires two recursive calls, so clearly they can't *both* be in that position -- but one of them can, so *that* tail-call can be converted to a `while` loop:

Original (pseudocode):

```
quicksort(i, j) {
    return if j <= i
    k = getPivot(i, j)
    partition(i, j, k)
    quicksort(i, k-1)    <--- This recursive call can't be changed
    quicksort(k+1, j)    <--- This recursive call is amenable to TCO
}
```

After TCO:

```
quicksort(i, j) {
    while (j > i) {
        k = getPivot(i, j)
        partition(i, j, k)
        quicksort(i, k-1)    <--- This recursive call is unchanged
        i = k+1
    }
}
```

Calling them in the opposite order would also work.

Comment: Could you go a little more into what you mean by "final position?"  In your TCO example you set `i` after the recursive call to quicksort.  What makes the call final?

Comment: @louism2: `i` is set in the version where the second recursive call is eliminated, setting the loop limit in place of the parameter to the (now eliminated) final recursive call.

Comment: (up with good answers. down with comment filters.) The order of the calls to the recursive function is important. If you make sure that the tail call is for the larger partition, then you guarantee that the maximum stack depth is no more than `log2(n)` even if partitions are badly chosen.

Comment: @louism2: That `i = k+1` assignment replaces a recursive call that *was* final, which is the important condition.  When you (or the compiler) performs TCO, you have to set up the parameters so that at the top of the while loop it looks just like the function was called.  In this case the second parameter doesn't change, but if it did (e.g. for some other TCO-able recursive algorithm), you would need an assignment to j as well.